# @mixin not defined in saas file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, saas

This is asset file structure in my rails app

```
assets
-- stylesheets
----- application.scss
----- homes.scss
```

**Gemfile** contains

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

**application.scss** contains

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**homes.scss** contains

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
   .shop{
     height: 250px;
     border: solid 1px #000;
   }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {  }
```

When I run the application, these mixins (@screen-sm-min, @screen-md-min, @screen-lg-min) are not defined. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I'll be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Sass’ `import` statement behaves slightly different than CSS’ in this context as it will make the mixin available at the time the Sass code is compiled to CSS. Your application compiles both `home.scss` and `application.scss` individually which means that the mixins in question are not available within `home.scss` at the time the CSS is compiled since they’re not imported in this context.

You will have to either rename `home.scss` to `_home.scss` and include it into your `application.scss` file and then only serve that with your mark–up (assuming that you’re currently serving both) or import the bootstrap dependencies at the top of your `home.scss` file as well.